# Issues with character controller (unity 4 project in unity 5)

Tags: c#, unity, movement

I'm having the weirdest issues with a game me and a mate have been working on. They came up immediately after moving from the last version of Unity 4 to Unity 5.

The two objects (player and enemy) return an error "**Character Controller Settings are invalid**" both on starting and stopping the game.

The enemy settings are:

```
Slope Limit:        50
Step Offset:        60
Skin Width:         0.003
Min Move Distance:  0
Center:            (0, 0, 0)
Radius:             0.01 
Height:             0.01
```

some of the values have had to be scaled down to accommodate for the scale of the actual model.

Then, whenever the "Move" function calls (which use to have the enemy move towards the player), I get

**CharacterController.Move called on inactive controller**

which I have located to come from this code:

`_controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);`

where moveDirection is just a Vector3 co-ordinate of where to move too.

as I said, this was all working before I converted to the new version of Unity. I have checked and confirmed that the Character Controller is both correctly linked and enabled. I have not found anything useful looking up problems others have had with a similar error, and it's pretty much got me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since identified that this may have been corruption resulting from an upgrade of Unity versions mid-project.

As I have had many other weird problems as a result of updating Unity, since, this is the best I have come up with. I will consider any future answer that goes to better effort to explain why it was happening, and would advise anybody facing a similar issue to greatly consider waiting until after project completion before performing updates to Unity.